# Как сделать поиск по произвольному (tv) полю Modx?

Tags: php, modx

Суть проблемы такова, что сейчас на сайте поиск производится по названию ресурса. Необходимо изменить на одно поле из "Дополнительных полей" это будет улица.
В админке нашел сниппет поиска, в нем идет запрос по выборке ресурсов, это понятно:

```
$heap = $modx->getCollection('modResource', 
    "`template` = '4' 
    AND `pagetitle` 
    LIKE '%{$search}%' AND `deleted` = '0' 
    AND `published` = '1'");
```

Изменил "pagetitle" на свое поле "location" и ничего не нашлось. Погуглив нашел что дополнительные поля не находятся в этом объекте (смотрел в файле `core/model/schema/modx.mysql.schema.xml`)
Как можно сделать такой поиск?

Версия - MODX Revolution 2.3.3 pl
Спасибо.

И еще один вопрос, как сделать сортировку по полю для всех ресурсов? Т.е. во всех категориях сортировалось по полю.

Answer (score 0):

TV-параметры никак не относятся к `modResource`. Доступ к ним возможен через класс `modTemplateVarResource`. И уже там храниться id ресурса к которому относится значение этого поля.

Стало быть, для поиска, например, всех ресурсов у которых значение **myTv** содержит число **11** надо сделать примерно так:

```
$q = $modx->newQuery('modResource');
$q->leftJoin('modTemplateVarResource', 'TemplateVarResources');
$q->leftJoin('modTemplateVar', 'tv', "tv.id=TemplateVarResources.tmplvarid");

$search = 11; // Искомая фраза (для примера)

$q->where(array(
    array(
        'tv.name'   => 'myTv', // имя tv-поля по которому ищем
        'TemplateVarResources.value:LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%', // Условие поиска
        'parent' => 229, // Родитель
        'deleted' => 0, // Не удалён
        'published' => 1 // Опубликован
    )
));
$resources = $modx->getCollection('modResource', $q);

foreach ($resources as $id => $res) {
  $output .= $res->get('pagetitle').'<br>';
}

return $output;
```

---

Также, можно воспользоваться [pdoResources](https://docs.modx.pro/components/pdotools/snippets/pdoresources). Он прекрасно ищет по значению тв-параметров. И с сортировкой по доп. полям, тоже спокойно справится:

```
$output = $modx->runSnippet('pdoResources',array(
    'limit' => 15,
    'parents' => 229,
    'tpl' => 'myTpl',
    'includeTVs' => 'myTv',
    'where' => '{"myTv:LIKE":"%11%"}',
    'sortby' => '{"myTv":"ASC"}'
));
```

Comment: А если нада сделать выборку по нескольким TV???

Comment: @МишанДега самое простое через pdoResources, как в последнем примере. Условием выборки будет, что-то такое: `'where' => '{"tv1":"110", "tv2":"45"}'` . На выходе получим ресурсы из категории с id = 229, у которых `tv1 - 110`, а `tv2 - 45`